# As alterações em meu site não aparecem

Tags: servidor, google-chrome, cache

Meu site esta configurado no servidor em vps com easyengine. Quando eu insiro alguma mudança no arquivo css ou em qualquer outro, não aparece as alterações no meu site. Ja tentei limpar o cache e nada... Ja inclui o ssl no site e no chrome não aparece o https e nem as novas alterações.... Abri o site depois no firefox e esta aparecendo... Mas se eu faço uma nova alteração no css por exemplo, não aparece! Estou deis de ontem.. limpei o cache do navegador e nada... Tem alguma configuração a ser feita no servidor?

Comment: Tente apertar CTRL+F5

Comment: caso não resolva, veirifque se seu servidor tem  alguma forma de cache de aramazenamento se tiver desative-o, exemplo o uol o cloud fire tudo utiliza essa forma

Comment: Experimente colocar o link do css com parâmetros novos a cada alteração para ver se consegue ver as alterações novas. `estilo.css?v=1`

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi!!!!
Eu apenas desabilitei atraves do easyengine utilizando o comando:

```
ee site disable dominio.com.br
```

E depois habilitei usando:

```
ee site enable dominio.com.br
```

E assim apareceram as ultimas atualizações.... Não sei se é a maneira mais correta, mas resolveu! :)